# sqlite3 create view syntax wrong

Tags: sqlite

I wrote a piece of sqlite3 query as following:

```
CREATE TABLE appearances(
    char_id int,
    comic_id int
); 
CREATE VIEW co-actors AS 
    SELECT a1.char_id,
           a2.char_id 
    FROM appearances AS a1 
    LEFT JOIN appearances AS a2 ON a1.comic_id=a2.comic_id;
```

And it keeps showing up syntax error near '_' in the command shell.
Can anybody help me correct the query? Thanks~

One more question, if I want to select from the View I just created, how do I reference the column,like a1.char_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `co-actors` to `co_actors`
You are using a `-` where you should be using a `_`.

Comment: if I want a1.char_id,a2.char_id as a whole to be distinct, what should I do?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT a1.char_id, a2.char_id FROM ...` will cause duplicate rows to be removed from the set of result rows.

Comment: Do I need to put close parenthesis before a1 and after a2 since I need both of them as a whole to be unique?

Comment: No, the syntax I showed is for distinct rows; all columns will be included.